# How do I stop this video from autoplay on my blog? I've tried everything

Tags: flash, autoplay

```
< object id="flashobject" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowScriptAccess="always" 
  allowFullScreen="true" allowNetworking="all" height="442" width="720" 
  data="http://www.thedoctorstv.com/UMInterface_Tremor.swf?at=01823b09-1298-4bc6-a9fe-b70810b73213">
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.thedoctorstv.com/UMInterface_Tremor.swf?at=01823b09-1298-4bc6-a9fe-b70810b73213" />
  <param name="flashvars"
  value="programID=4ded41f8b81bc&config=http://r.unicornmedia.com/embed/01823b09-1298-4bc6-a9fe-b70810b73213?view=item%26view_id=4d91c6ec-dcaf-4861-939d-2c57052d1ab5" /></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, flash movie will need to have a `stop();` action in the first frame of the first scene in order to not play right away, regardless of what the parameters say in the `<object>` tag. Additionally, a button hotspot would need to be added over the entire flash movie that initates the `play();` command when the viewer clicks on it. I'm not sure that you can do anything about it without owning the original .fla file.

```
on (release){
play();
}
```

A possible work around would be to try and screenshot the first frame of the flash movie and make a static image out of it. Then try to find a script that "swaps" content on a click. Put the static image on your page and have it "swap" to the flash content when the viewer clicks.

Source: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15583